# SMPP Client that exposes a webservice

Tags: apache-camel, smpp, smsmanager, smslib, jsmpp

Does this exist?

None of these: SMSLib, JSMPP, Cloudhopper, Apache Camel
Expose a webservice

I´ve managed to create my own webservice using SMSLib, but I´ve had problems in the past: 
 [SMSLib: After getting NO_ROUTE, what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986505/smslib-after-getting-no-route-what-should-i-do)

So I´d like a more higher level application, in which I dont have to code anything. It sounds reasonable to me.

Today, my main application makes HTTP calls to this webservice, `https://.../sendSMS?to=...&body=....`

Answer (score 0):

You will certainly do not find it in pure SMPP libraries. You can probably find applications which can do it (often old, big, ugly and paid ones).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of months after I posted the question have passed.
SMSLib has "SMSServer" (org.smslib.smsserver), which does exactly this.

http://smslib.org/doc/smsserver/

It does expose a kind of webservice, with 3 URL's

- "server-ip:port/" - list of gateways
- "server-ip:port/send" - send a SMS
- "server-ip:port/read" - read SMSs that where sent to a gateway

Also, Kannel exposes URLs too:

http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.0/userguide-1.4.0/userguide.html#AEN4064

- `http://....:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=foo&password=bar&to=0123456&text=Hello+world`